# Drag and drop in master detail in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I've been struggling to have drag and drop working on a master/detail split view in iOS in Swift. It works between two views when the master is hidden. However, when the master view is visible, the drag starts but the drop is not activated. Is there anyway to have it working?
Cheers.